# Inline validation technique, how to validate the LAST input in a form?

Tags: html, forms, validation

Much thought has already gone into practices around validating the user input in a form. I have a programming question about the "inline validation", also called "onblur validation". (A research article about the benefits of inline validation can be found [here](http://alistapart.com/article/inline-validation-in-web-forms)).

Let's say I have a very simple form with 5 inputs and 1 submit button at the bottom. The user focusse on the first field first. After pressing tab or manually clicking on it, he goes to the second input. This triggers the validation of input field 1. Depending on the techniques used, this might take a few seconds (for example, if a server postback is required to truly validate the field).

MY problem lies with the last field. User will be expecting to see the inline validation after they're done. But users do generally not tab if the next ui element is a button instead of yet another input element. Thus, the onblur validation will not trigger and the user gets no feedback, which they might mistake for erronous input. If they manually click on the submit button, the validation will trigger... but it will also trigger the total form submit, likely leading to another page if all is valid. Now, some users might be smart enough to realize this is onblur validation and they should "click anywhere" to trigger the validation, but I can't really count on that.

I thought of one solution: using the keypress event instead of the onblur event for the last input field of a form. However, the article cited above states it is better to avoid this kind of validation. It would also drastically increase the amount of validation to be done (one time for every keypress)

What are your thoughts on trying to mimic the nonexistant event "user stopped typing but did not focus out of input element"? Can it be done by combineing the keypress event and a timer? (Like, if user did not type anything for 2 seconds, then validate?)

Comment: The best thing to do is run the validation on keyup and add a delay timer. That way, instead of validating the field on every key press, it waits until the user is done typing. I usually set my timers for around 2000ms(2 seconds) which gives the user enough time to finish typing. (just got to the bottom of your question and it looks like you were on the right track with your thought process ;P)

Comment: @APAD1 Let's say I implement a delay that waits for 2 seconds. How can I code it in javascript/jquery so that if a new keyup event triggers before the previous' events two seconds have finished, the previous event will no longer execute after the two seconds are done?

Comment: Adding an example below

Comment: Why not simply implement validation to be triggered on form submit as well – and then, when the user does that, maybe change the submit button to read _“Validating data, please wait …”_ or sth. similar, additionally deactivating the submit button temporarily … and start your validation. If it is successful, finish the form submit you previously canceled by submitting the form via JS, and otherwise show them the validation errors and reset submit button text and active status.

Comment: @CBRoe A user using our forms is accustomed to seeing instant validation. He will not want to press the submit button if the last field did not validate. He will idly wait a few seconds and stare at the input pondering why it isn't validating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    var typingTimer;                //timer identifier
    var doneTypingInterval = 2000;  //time in ms

    $('input[type="email"]').keyup(function(){
        clearTimeout(typingTimer); //reset the timer
        typingTimer = setTimeout(validateEmail, doneTypingInterval);
    });
```

Change `validateEmail` to the name of the function that validates the email input.

Comment: Although I can't find any real research on what the "best" timeout value is given context or user "XYZ", I guess anything between 1 and 3 seconds is plausible and yields the effect I want. thanks!

Comment: Ya, it's hard to determine what the best timeout would be since everyone types at different speeds. If my target audience is younger, I usually assume that they are pretty quick typers and set the timeout at around 2 seconds. If the audience is older I might extend it by a second or two ;) Good luck!